# Rotation matrix to move to a different basis

Tags: matrices, rotations, change-of-basis

I have three unit vectors x', y', and z' in R^3.

I wish to calculate a 3x3 rotation matrix M such that:

```
M x [1,0,0] -> x'
M x [0,1,0] -> y'
M x [0,0,1] -> z'
```

How can I generate M from the new unit vectors?

Comment: The columns of $M$ are the transformed basis vectors: $M=[x' \quad y'\quad z']$

Comment: In case this isn't well defined, I can state my problem more specifically.  I have a line defined by the start and end points s and e.  I take as x'  norm(e-s).  y' is defined as cross(x', [0,0,1]), then z' is cross(x',y').  basically, I want a transform matrix which rotates x to be on the line, and I generate two reasonable other vectors to fill out the basis.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in the comment that you choose the vectors as follows
$$
y'=x'\times\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}x'_2\\-x'_1\\0\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad z'=x'\times y'=\left(\begin{matrix}x_1'x_3'\\x_2'x_3'\\-(x_1')^2-(x_2')^2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
The columns of
$$
M=(x',y',z')
$$
are orthogonal but not normalized (except $x'$ by your choice). For $M$ to be a rotation matrix the determinant must be $+1\,.$ With unnormalized $y',z'$ the determinant is
\begin{align}
{\rm det}(M)&=(x_1')^4+(x_1')^2(x_2')^2+(x_2')^2(x_3')^2+(x_1')^2(x_3')^2+(x_2')^4+(x_1')^2(x_2')^2\\[3mm]
&=((x_1')^2+(x_2')^2)^2+((x_1')^2+(x_2')^2)(x_3')^2\,,\\[3mm]
&=((x_1')^2+(x_2')^2)\underbrace{((x_1')^2+(x_2')^2+(x_3')^2)}_{||x'||^2=1}\,.
\end{align}
From
$||y'||=\sqrt{(x_1')^2+(x_2')^2}$
it follows that
$$
||z'||=||y'||
$$
so that ${\det}(M)=||y'||\,||z'||\,.$ This shows that the determinant
will be one once $y'$ and $z'$ are normalized.

The rotation angle $\alpha$ is the angle between $(0,1,0)^\top$ and its image $y'\,.$ This is
$$
\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{-(x_1')^2}{\sqrt{(x_1')^2+(x_2')^2}}\right)\,.
$$

Comment: I have a bad habit of forgetting that the cross product of two normalised vectors is not normalised.  Thank you for this, it's great.